# In ruby, I can't get byebug to work with selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, irb, byebug

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'byebug'

byebug

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome

driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

puts driver.find_element(:tag_name, 'input');
puts driver.find_element(:name, 'q');

driver.find_element(:name, 'q').send_keys("asdf");
#sleep 20
```

When I run the program, it goes straight to `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome`

I hit 'n',  then it loads Chrome, and goes to google and sends those keys into the input box and exits the program.

What I'd like to happen is that I hit 'n' it goes to `driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"`.  I hit 'n' again, it goes to  `puts driver.find_element(:tag_name, 'input');`.  And I would like from the console to run commands like driver.find_element....   But I can't because byebug isn't tracing through the program after the `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome` line.

I want to be able to check out the DOM with Selenium from the console / irb / byebug

**Added**

A comment suggests using pry

So I tried `require 'pry'` and `binding.pry`. And 'next' rather than 'n'(as pry uses 'next'). Same problem.

And I tried `require 'pry-byebug'` and `'binding.pry'` and 'next' rather than 'n'(as pry-byebug uses 'next'). Also same problem.

On rs's suggestion, I tried `require 'pry'` and `require 'pry-byebug'` and binding.pry(to halt). And tried `step` rather than `next`. Also, same problem.  I have now added output of this.

**Added Further**

```
Apples-MBP:rubyselenium1 apple$ cat selenium12.rb 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962313/in-ruby-i-cant-get-byebug-to-work-with-selenium?noredirect=1#comment94763217_53962313

    require 'selenium-webdriver'
    require 'pry'
    require 'pry-byebug'

    binding.pry

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome

    driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

    puts driver.find_element(:tag_name, 'input');
    puts driver.find_element(:name, 'q');

    driver.find_element(:name, 'q').send_keys("asdf");
    #sleep 20

Apples-MBP:rubyselenium1 apple$ ruby selenium12.rb 
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      ffi (>= 1.0.11, ~> 1.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.

From: /Users/apple/rubyselenium1/selenium12.rb @ line 9 :

     4:     require 'pry'
     5:     require 'pry-byebug'
     6:  
     7:     binding.pry
     8:     
 =>  9:     driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:chrome
    10:     
    11:     driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
    12:  
    13:     puts driver.find_element(:tag_name, 'input');
    14:     puts driver.find_element(:name, 'q');

[1] pry(main)> step

From: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb @ line 86 Selenium::WebDriver.for:

    85: def self.for(*args)
 => 86:   WebDriver::Driver.for(*args)
    87: end

[1] pry(Selenium::WebDriver)> step

From: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb @ line 42 Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for:

    41: def for(browser, opts = {})
 => 42:   case browser
    43:   when :chrome
    44:     Chrome::Driver.new(opts)
    45:   when :internet_explorer, :ie
    46:     IE::Driver.new(opts)
    47:   when :safari
    48:     Safari::Driver.new(opts)
    49:   when :phantomjs
    50:     PhantomJS::Driver.new(opts)
    51:   when :firefox, :ff
    52:     Firefox::Driver.new(opts)
    53:   when :edge
    54:     Edge::Driver.new(opts)
    55:   when :remote
    56:     Remote::Driver.new(opts)
    57:   else
    58:     raise ArgumentError, "unknown driver: #{browser.inspect}"
    59:   end
    60: end

[1] pry(Selenium::WebDriver::Driver)> step

From: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb @ line 44 Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for:

    41: def for(browser, opts = {})
    42:   case browser
    43:   when :chrome
 => 44:     Chrome::Driver.new(opts)
    45:   when :internet_explorer, :ie
    46:     IE::Driver.new(opts)
    47:   when :safari
    48:     Safari::Driver.new(opts)
    49:   when :phantomjs
    50:     PhantomJS::Driver.new(opts)
    51:   when :firefox, :ff
    52:     Firefox::Driver.new(opts)
    53:   when :edge
    54:     Edge::Driver.new(opts)
    55:   when :remote
    56:     Remote::Driver.new(opts)
    57:   else
    58:     raise ArgumentError, "unknown driver: #{browser.inspect}"
    59:   end
    60: end

[1] pry(Selenium::WebDriver::Driver)> step

From: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb @ line 40 Kernel#require:

    35:   #
    36:   # The normal <tt>require</tt> functionality of returning false if
    37:   # that file has already been loaded is preserved.
    38: 
    39:   def require path
 => 40:     RUBYGEMS_ACTIVATION_MONITOR.enter
    41: 
    42:     path = path.to_path if path.respond_to? :to_path
    43: 
    44:     if spec = Gem.find_unresolved_default_spec(path)
    45:       Gem.remove_unresolved_default_spec(spec)

[1] pry(main)> step

From: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb @ line 184 MonitorMixin#mon_enter:

    183: def mon_enter
 => 184:   if @mon_owner != Thread.current
    185:     @mon_mutex.lock
    186:     @mon_owner = Thread.current
    187:     @mon_count = 0
    188:   end
    189:   @mon_count += 1
    190: end

[1] pry(#<Monitor>)> step

From: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb @ line 185 MonitorMixin#mon_enter:

    183: def mon_enter
    184:   if @mon_owner != Thread.current
 => 185:     @mon_mutex.lock
    186:     @mon_owner = Thread.current
    187:     @mon_count = 0
    188:   end
    189:   @mon_count += 1
    190: end

[1] pry(#<Monitor>)> step
before_session hook failed: ThreadError: deadlock; recursive locking
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:185:in `lock'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
[1] pry(#<Monitor>)> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    29: from selenium12.rb:9:in `<main>'
    28: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
    27: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `for'
    26: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    25: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:186:in `mon_enter'
    24: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/context.rb:98:in `at_line'
    23: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.6.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:63:in `at_line'
    22: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.6.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:111:in `resume_pry'
    21: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.6.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:27:in `run'
    20: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.6.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:27:in `catch'
    19: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.6.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:28:in `block in run'
    18: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/byebug-10.0.2/lib/byebug/helpers/eval.rb:94:in `allowing_other_threads'
    17: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.6.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    16: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.6.0/lib/byebug/processors/pry_processor.rb:113:in `block in resume_pry'
    15: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:348:in `repl'
    14: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
    13: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
    12: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
    11: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
    10: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:68:in `block in repl'
     7: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:108:in `read'
     6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/indent.rb:394:in `correct_indentation'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/terminal.rb:8:in `screen_size'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/terminal.rb:33:in `actual_screen_size'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/terminal.rb:47:in `screen_size_according_to_io_console'
     2: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
     1: from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:185:in `mon_enter'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:185:in `lock': deadlock; recursive locking (ThreadError)
Apples-MBP:rubyselenium1 apple$ 
Apples-MBP:rubyselenium1 apple$
```

Comment: it sounds like it is working .... but, you can always try pry insteadd

Comment: @maxpleaner just tried pry and even pry-byebug, and added a note to my question re them. same problem

Comment: What happens if you use `step` instead of `next`?

Comment: @TomLord pry says "before_session hook failed: ThreadError: deadlock; recursive locking
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:185:in `lock'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)"

Comment: @barlop just use next if you dont want to step into the code and just need to go from one statment to the other,  i see the in the code above that it halts correctly, next should take you to : driver.navigate.to "http://google.com" and subsequently to the lines below that.

Comment: You were telling me to use step . I will try next now

Comment: when I try it with 'next', then it just runs the put statements and exits the program. It doesn't stop at each put statement

Answer (score 0):

This gem "Adds step-by-step debugging and stack navigation capabilities to pry using byebug." {quoted from [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug)}, So you need pry and byebug both inorder to use pry byebug. So ensure both gems are installed: you can add both gems to your GemFile and do `bundle install` or just do that directly, after that you should require both and then add `binding.pry` execution will stop at the first statment after that.

"The aliases `'n', 's', 'c' and 'f'`  were removed by default because they usually conflict with scratch variable names. But it's very easy to reenable them if you still want them, just add the following shortcuts to your ~/.pryrc file:"

```
if defined?(PryByebug)
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'c', 'continue'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 's', 'step'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'n', 'next'
  Pry.commands.alias_command 'f', 'finish'
end
```

More detailed info in the link i provided above, hope this helps.

**added by barlop**

rs comments that questioner try `require pry` and `require pry-byebug` and halt with `binding.pry`

Comment: this is totally irrelevant, I'm well aware that there's a way to map 'n' for 'next' pry-byebug. That's not what I was asking at all

Comment: @barlop so a couple of things led to this answer: 1st you are using byebug to stop execution which is not corrcet, so I  suggested binding.pry, pry is not required in your code above, so i believe thats causing your execution to not halt, so i suggested to require it and lastly your comment on hitting 'n', led me to believe that you may have not added these aliases to~/.pryrc file:", so in my assesment the answer is not irrelevant unless i missed what your actual issue was, i will leave it to your best judgement however, if you feel the answer didnt help

Comment: thanks. But see the note I already added to my question, it shows that I also tried `require 'pry'`/ `binding.pry`. (i.e. I tried it without byebug)

Comment: i have been using pry with and without byebug successfully for a while on my project, not sure why its causing an issue, the only additional thing i can sugges is that you can probably check your Gemset and gemlist to ensure you are  using the correct gemset ( rvm gemset list) and that gemset has pry in it (gem list). you may have done that already but just a suggestion.

Comment: I am not using rvm but if I do `gem list` it says `pry (0.11.3, 0.10.4)`

Comment: oh i just noticed in your comment above that you tried pry without byebug and tried to use next, that wont help if thats the case, you need to require both  pry and pry byebug to use: "continue", "next", "step" and "finish". if you havent tried this, give it  a try and see if it helps.

Comment: So are you saying I should do `require 'pry'` and `require 'pry-byebug'` and then what do I use to pause it? `binding.pry` or `byebug` or something else?

Comment: Yeah you need to require both and then just use binding.pry to halt execution. you will then be able use next, finish, continue, step, you should get it to work, also check the GitHub in my answer above, byebug is not required, just make sure you have both pry and pry byebug in your gem list

Comment: Thanks.  I have added relevant output to my question.   I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The following is a partial answer. It doesn't solve the pry / byebug / pry-byebug issue, but it does address this part,

One of the things the question asks is

> "I want to be able to check out the DOM with Selenium from the console
>   / irb / byebug"

Code using Selenium does run OK typed straight into irb

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true

irb(main):011:0> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Marionette::Driver:0x..fcead308af2433ac2 browser=:firefox>

irb(main):013:0> driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com")
=> nil

irb(main):036:0> inps=driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "input");
=> [#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f8ed35db92a849eea id="dac....

irb(main):041:0> inps[2].attribute('name');
=> "q"

irb(main):042:0> inps[2].attribute('value');
=> ""  <-- shows whatever is typed in that google search box eg prior to checking the value we could've typed something e.g. 'asdf' into it manually or programmatically eg driver.find_element(:tag_name, "input").send_keys("asdf");  and it will show "asdf".
```